# How to check time range while adding a new record in a table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access table called "Reservations" and an Access form called "Reservations Form".

**Reservation Table**

| Employee_Name | Service_Name | Service Hours | Start_DateTime | End_DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Head Massage | 2 hours | 31-Dec-20 3:00:00 PM | 31-Dec-20 5:00:00 PM |
| Bob | Foot Massage | 1 hour | 31-Dec-20 3:00:00 PM | 31-Dec-20 4:00:00 PM |

**The form structure**

```
Employee_Name : (Input Field)
Service_Name : (Input Field)
Service_Hours : (Input Field)
Start_DateTime : (Input Date Time Field)
End_DateTime : (Input Date Time Field)
```

**Sample Data in the form**

```
Employee_Name : John
Service_Name : Head Massage
Service_Hours : 2 Hours
Start_DateTime : 31-Dec-20 4:00:00 PM
End_DateTime : 31-Dec-20 5:00:00 PM
```

We can't accept two reservations for the same employee on the same day and same time.
There is a reservation for John from 31-Dec-20 3:00:00 PM to 31-Dec-20 5:00:00 PM.
No other reservation can be accepted in this time period.

If a new reservation is submitted by the reservation form we need to check the Date and time with employee name.
John is already reserved from 31-Dec-20 3:00:00 PM to 31-Dec-20 5:00:00 PM.
He is not available for the new reservation (From 31-Dec-20 4:00:00 PM to 31-Dec-20 5:00:00 PM).

**VBA Code**

```vb
Private Sub Command11_Click()
    Dim strWhere                 As String
    Dim dtRequeestStartDate      As Date
    Dim dtRequestEndDate         As Date
    
    dtRequestStartDate = Me![Text1].Value
    dtRequestEndDate = Me![Text2].Value
        
    If (DCount("Employee_Name", "Reservations", "Employee_Name=""" & [Employee_Name].Value & """ AND #" & Format(dtRequestStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & "# <= EndDate" & " and #" & Format(dtRequestEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & "#  >= StartDate") <> 0) Then
      MsgBox "Can't book a reservation."
    End If
```

I get an error

> The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'EndDate'

Comment: What is the full error message and on which line does it occur? Have you checked all your datatypes are as expected?

Comment: I want to check the date and time with the employee name. If I add this code (strWhere = strWhere & " And dtEmployee_Name = 'John'"), then it will gives an error for this line(If (DCount("*", "Reservations", strWhere) <> 0) Then).

Comment: yes sir. That is the error

Comment: I edited the codes in the question. Please check and help me.

Comment: It looks you have no `EndDate` field. (Neither `StartDate` but the parser stops at the first error.) I suggest to assemble a syntactically workable query first, e.g. `Dim s As String :  s = "Employee_Name", "Reservations", ... `, and set a breakpoint there to check if `s` is perfect. You can even issue that command in the immediate window to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Field names for date fields used in criteria are not same as field names shown in table.

Might want to first validate that requested dates are for a future date, not a typo with last month or last year. Can use ValidationRule property of textbox: `>=Now()`.

As is now, both start and end date must be within range for request to be rejected. Should probably check if either start OR end date is between already reserved range. In other words, check for overlapping ranges.

```
AND (#" & Format(dtRequestStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & "# BETWEEN Start_DateTime AND End_DateTime OR #" & _
Format(dtRequestEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & "# BETWEEN Start_DateTime AND End_DateTime)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that is starting to look quite nice.

The idea of the "strWhere" you have (and I see you not using it) is simply to help in writing the code (and I suppose to save some days in rooms requring padded walls).

How do you eat a elephant?
Answer: one bite at a time.

So, the idea here is to break this down into smaller and smaller parts - so small that this becomes a walk in the park.

So, we first need (and want) to setup a date/range test/criteria.

So, this should do the trick:

```
Dim strWhere                 As String
Dim dtRequeestStartDate      As Date
Dim dtRequestEndDate         As Date

dtRequestStartDate = Me![Text1].Value
dtRequestEndDate = Me![Text2].Value

ftime = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM"


strWhere = "#" & Format(dtRequestStartDate, ftime) & "# <= End_DateTime" & _
    " and #" & Format(dtRequestEndDate, ftime) & "#  >= Start_DateTime"
```

So, that takes care of our date range. but we also need to add to the above the staff.

So, we simply add it to above.

```
strWhere = strWhere & " AND "Employee_Name = '" & [Employee_Name].Value & "'"
```

So, see why we have the strWhere. We don't have to do this, but now we can break this down, and add one or even 5 more criteria to the where clause.
So, now that we have strWhere with the date range, and with the staff?

Then we can use dcount()

dcount() is

```
dcount("some field name", "some table name", "some where clause")
```

So, that's the syntax for dcount(). In fact, dlookup(), and dcount() are much the same. The only real differance is that lookup() returns a value, while dcount() returns a count.

In this case, all we care if the request has a count of 1, or 20 or whatever (anything greater then 0 is a collision).

So, now we have the criteria loaded up into that where clause?

Then we can use dcount() like this:

```
If DCount("*", "Reservations", strWhere) > 0 then
  MsgBox "Can't book a reservation."

End If
```

So you can see why the suggest to load up the criteria into the strWhere. It just allows the code to be read oh so much with greater ease. And note I used "*" for the first value in dcount(). You could put in "id" or any column you want - but we really don't care, since we are just counting rows - we ONLY care if we have a result of > 0.

So, in summary, we have quite much this code:

```
Dim strWhere                 As String
Dim dtRequeestStartDate      As Date
Dim dtRequestEndDate         As Date
Dim ftime                    As String

ftime = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM"

dtRequestStartDate = Me![Text1].Value
dtRequestEndDate = Me![Text2].Value

' date range critera
strWhere = "#" & Format(dtRequestStartDate, ftime) & "# <= End_DateTime" & _
    " and #" & Format(dtRequestEndDate, ftime) & "#  >= Start_DateTime"

' employee criteria
strWhere = strWhere & " AND Employee_Name = '" & [Employee_Name].Value & "'"

' doctors exam room criteria
' ok - we don't' have  any!!!, but we can add many more criteria.

' now data pull - check for existing - 

If DCount("*", "Reservations", strWhere) > 0 then
    MsgBox "Can't book a reservation."
else
   ' ok to book - call routines to add this record to reservations
End If
```